# How to delete object without retrieving it in EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

We have a table that has a couple of nText columns so looking to delete a rows without retrieving it if possible

Another twist is that we don't know the IDentity value but a couple of other values that identify the row uniquely so examples such as the one below won't work as is

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/27/tip-9-deleting-an-object-without-retrieving-it.aspx

Hoping there's something newer in EF5 to address this without resorting to stored procs ?

Comment: It always bugged me that there's no equivalent to `DELETE ... WHERE X`. You can `stuff.Select(x => x.Thing == thing)` but you can't `stuff.Delete(x => x.Thing == thing)`. Actually, that's a candidate for an extension method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ExecuteStoreCommand`

For example:

```
databaseContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM [table] where ... ");
```

Comment: He need to delete rows without recovering objects, I thing ExecuteStoreCommand fits.